# Finding DE-9IM matrix in Spatialite?

Tags: spatialite

Is there a way to find the DE-9IM matrix using a spatialite function?

I realize that one can use relate() function to determine if two geometries match a matrix, but I would like to get the matrix instead.

I find it useful to examine DE-9IM matrices when trying to determining whether there are slivers or the like in a JOIN ON INTERSECTS();

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Relate.html

Answer (score 0):

Spatialite also has ST_Relate implemented. Both Spatialite and Postgis expose this from the GEOS library.
For Spatialite see: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html :

*"ST_Relate( geom1 Geometry , geom2 Geometry , patternMatrix String ) : Integer
 returns TRUE if the spatial relationship specified by the patternMatrix holds"*

Where "patternMatrix" is meant the same as "intersectionMatrixPattern" in the Postgis docs.